# What do the grey dashed lines in IDA's text view represent?

Tags: ida

[image: IDA Pro Screenshot]

What are grey dashed lines supposed to represent in IDA? I am new to IDA + new to reverse engineering in general. I originally thought these marked functions that IDA hadn't defined but looking into blocks that don't return etc this probably isn't the case.

Could anyone enlighten me on what these signify?

Comment: in  a function that is huge when the compiler optimizes it it breaks the functions into chunks by determining​ which code paths would be used most and places them in  an order to maximize performance  when a disassembler  analyses the function it may identify the chunks and would put them in blocks    with those markers around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

begin/end of block, may be possible a function or unlink switch table